# What does 'erase personal data' tool actually erase?

Tags: privacy

What does 'erase personal data' tool actually erase?

- User generated content (comments / posts/pages etc. if they can publish)?
- Keep all data except user's name in comments?

https://wordpress.org/support/article/tools-erase-personal-data-screen/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User generated content, including comments, are not deleted - the author name, email, IP address etc is simply anonymized so it can no longer be linked to that user.

Nor is the user account account deleted - you would need to decide whether you wanted to do that manually or not.

The Personal Data Eraser functionality has also been designed so it can be [added to your custom plugins](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/privacy/adding-the-personal-data-eraser-to-your-plugin/).

Comment: so what's actually deleted if user account is kept?